# How I add multiple popover to ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, popover

I am making an app guide(coach mark) using Ionic 1.(use ionic 1, Angularjs)

The structure I think is like this. App guide seems like speech bubble.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qryN0.png)

I think maybe use $ionicPopover. but if another way exist, please recommend.

I had several popovers in a strange way, but I don't know how to put difference contents each popover.

In the example, there is only the same content in the popover(ex. click), but I want to put in a different content.

So I tried.

### js file.

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('widgets/guide-popover.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
    $scope.popoverList = "hi!";
}); 

$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('widgets/guide-popover.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover1 = popover;
    $scope.popoverList = "touch here.";
});
```

~~~

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function () {            
    $scope.popover.show(angular.element(document.querySelector(".poptest")));
    $scope.popover1.show(angular.element(document.querySelector(".poptest1")));
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.popover.hide(angular.element(document.querySelector(".poptest")));
        $scope.popover1.hide(angular.element(document.querySelector(".poptest1")));
    }, 4000);
});
```

---

pug file(html)

---

```
ion-popover-view
ion-content {{popoverList}}
```

---

Yes,I konw many problem exist. But in this code, The biggest problem is put the different values in one variable. Help please....